# No response when running a python script to install a windows service

Tags: python, pywin32

I used to run a python to register a windows service before. But I failed to register just now. I run the sample service register script and no single response. Just run and exit. No service of mine showed at the service manager. I do not know how to fix that. I tried many times for reinstall pywin32 and python. But it does not work anyway. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        print(333)


    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

And this is what I get after running the code:

> C:\Users\saige\Documents\flasky\flasky-first-edition-5a>python
>   create_service.py install
>
> C:\Users\saige\Documents\flasky\flasky-first-edition-5a>python
>   create_service.py install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed that bug with switching the python version. I found out that Python 3.7 does not support win32 in some ways. I installed the python 2.7 then it works. Of course, I changed the environment path variables and installed win32 for python 2.7 manually.